# Android Tablet "dp" difference

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I would like to create a adaptive UI for both mobile and tablet devices. I would like to know for example for mobile devices if I give `android:textsize="2dp` then how much I should give for tablet devices. I know I should give them in values-w820dp and appropriate folder but how to calculate the difference of this dp. I couldn't find any resource for this. Help me out.

Answer (score 1):

(1) For most text, it's best to size it in `sp` units so it scales automatically relative to the user's text-size preference. Folks with lesser vision can pick larger text and then be able to read your app without eyestrain.

(2) If you need some text to appear in a fixed size, e.g. a big headline, then use `dp` units so it scales automatically relative to the screen's pixel density. (Pixel density is independent of the overall screen size. It's a high vs. low density thing, not a phone vs. tablet thing.)

But don't use size `2dp`! That'd be unreadably tiny -- the height of 2 physical pixels of a 160 dpi screen.

(3) If you need some text that uses approximately a fixed proportion of the screen size, then it makes sense to either define screen-size-dependent parameters, e.g. in `values-w820dp`, or to size it in code.

(4) If you need some text in a fixed number of pixels tall even when the pixels are really tiny, e.g. to draw into a raster image, then use `px` units.

See [Supporting Multiple Screens - best practices](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence).

Answer (score 0):

There are no strict rules here. You can have `android:textsize="2dp` on your tablet as well if you wish so. You can have a look at the following [android developer page](https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html) which tells how to support tablets and contains chapter called: `5. Adjust Font Sizes and Touch Targets`

Comment: Yeah i know there is such strict rules. But when i give same dp to mobile and tab it differs. For example 8dp looks good for tab but when we look into tablet it looks bit small. Especially when the tablet screen size gets bigger. So this is the problem I'm facing! And thanks for ur link. Let me see what i can take from it.

Comment: Actually `dp` and similar units were created to eliminate the issue you are seeing. If you use `dp` it should look the same on every device. It may possibly look a little different depending on the dpi of your device. 
Please check whether using `sp` instead of `dp` helps. `sp` is designed for usage with text